# Num_rows looks to be failing, what to use instead?

Tags: php

User is being automatically redirected to the about page after clicking through instead of the new password showing. Can anyone see what might be wrong with the code here? It's for forgotten password functionality.

Is it a problem with num_rows?

PHP:

```html
if(isset($_GET['email']) && isset($_GET['token'])) {
  global $conn;

  $email = $_GET['email'];
  $token = $_GET['token'];

  $sql = $conn->query("SELECT u_id FROM users WHERE
    email='$email' AND
    token='$token' AND
    token<>'' AND
    tokenExpire > NOW()
    ");

    if($sql->num_rows > 0) {
      $newPassword = generateNewString();
      $newPasswordEncrypted = password_hash($newPassword, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
      $conn->query("UPDATE users SET token='', password = '$newPasswordEncrypted' WHERE
        email='$email'
      ");

      echo "Your new password is $newPassword";
    } else
      header("Location: " . BASE_URL . "/about.php");
} else {
  redirectToLoginPage();
}
```

Comment: **Warning**:You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized prepared statements instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](https://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187).

Comment: I know, thanks. I'm just trying to get it working for the moment then I'll convert them to PDO

Comment: Have you tried any debugging? Have you dumped the generated query and tried it directly on the database?

Comment: See [this comment in the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php#105289).